# Compiler complains about nested mapping in a structure

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

while writing a smart contract a keep having an error in solidity ^0.8.0 about a nested mapping in a structure, here is my code snippets :

```
     struct Airline {
     address airlineAddress;
     AirlineState state;
     string name;
     mapping(address => bool) approvals; // I guess this what cause the error
     uint8 approvalCount;
   }
```

```
constructor()
    {
      contractOwner = msg.sender;

      airlines[contractOwner] = Airline(contractOwner, AirlineState.Paid, "First Airline", 0); // This an error
      totalPaidAirlines++;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the error that you get, this will make it easier to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I put it in the subject, but the complete error msg appears like this  : "Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappings are only stored in storage. By initiating a struct in the constructor you assign it to memory. You should do it like this instead:

```
   struct Airline {
        address airlineAddress;
        AirlineState state;
        string name;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals; 
        uint8 approvalCount;
   }

   address contractOwner;
   mapping(address => Airline) airlines;
   uint8 totalPaidAirlines;
   constructor()
   {
      contractOwner = msg.sender;
      Airline storage airline = airlines[contractOwner]; //accessing the struct that is already in storage
      //one by one assigning the properties
      airline.airlineAddress = contractOwner;
      airline.state = AirlineState.Paid;
      airline.name = "First Airline";
      airline.approvalCount = 0; 
      totalPaidAirlines++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude your code work fine :)